# how to set the logger while calling ant target from java

Tags: java, shell, ant

I have to call an ant target from java class, currently it is being called from sh script where it sets -logger logger.class

I have written the java code to do so...

```
Project p = new Project();
        p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
        p.init();
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        helper.parse(p, buildFile);
        p.executeTarget(TARGET);
```

Can some one tell me how to set the logger using same code sequence.

error:

```
Class not found:util.logger.CustomLogger
java.lang.RuntimeException
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.createLogger(Main.java:850)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.addBuildListeners(Main.java:795)
```

Comment: Have you added the `CustomLogger` class to the classpath ?

Comment: yes Have added CustomLogger to class path

Answer (score 2):

You have to add your Logger to  the Project with addBuildListener, ant provides a few implementations which also implement `BuildLogger`

so

```
project.addBuildListener(new DefaultLogger());
```

or whatever your logger jave to be (as long as it implements `BuildListener`) should do the trick